# Download older version for free

Tags: after-effects, premiere, software-recommendation, adobe

I know that for Adobe CS2, Adobe released the program for free online due to some glitch or something.

But are there any (really good) NLE video editors what have been legally released for free online?

My objective is to gradually produce material - keeping costs low at startup - to then pay for products like Adobe Premier and AE. I am not a student so I can't swing that angle. However, my preference to Adobe is because of college.